# jpa entities on different applications

Tags: java, jpa

I have a java backend integration application (no UI) spring/jpa based.
now I am creating a UI web application (also spring/jpa based) to support queries on the backend  application.
So I will have two applications (jvms) using the same DB. 
My question is - will cahanges in the DB made by the backend integration application , be reflected on the jpa entities of the UI application ? or I have to force my entities to always go to the DB in order to be up to date ?

Comment: Yes, You correctly assume, problem exists (more or less). AFAIK portable part of JPA has no 'events' (Eclipselink maybe have, and totally not portable in some RBMS). No chance to be 'always' parallel, maybe correct question is "how many seconds is acceptable'

Comment: Totally orthodox, in JEE style, is to provide data and messaging via applicatrion server (maybe some machine than  web, maybe not). Maybe conceptually 'big challenge'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magical synchronisation of changes between the different JVMs. The UI application will only see changes that have been persisted into the DB by the backend application. So, in short, yes you will need to force DB persistence/lookup for your entities.

Note that you may also run into caching issues (for example, Hibernate does some automatic caching of entities by default). If the UI application has cached an entity, it will not see changes made by the backend application even if persisted into the DB, until the UI application does a new query to the DB itself as well.

Therefore I would advise you to test this thoroughly and adjust your configuration as necessary.

Comment: so I assume entityManager.refresh(entity) every where in my UI applcation before the actual query , will do no ?

Comment: Any 'refresh' initiative must be initiated at highest (GUI) level, and lower layers as a consequence

Comment: Using entityManager.refresh is one option of working around caching issues, yes. Note that you would typically use the refresh call *after* your database query, right before you actually do something with the entity.

Comment: ok I found it here https://dzone.com/articles/adding-entitymanagerrefresh-to-all-spring-data-rep . I need it with spring sata